# Update on form is redirecting to wrong route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a controller called admin and I'm using this to control logins etc... I have defined 'update' and 'edit' in the controller, but when I save, it redirects with an error. Is anybody able to assist? Been looking all morning and can't work it out! Seems to be adding a . instead of a slash when saving. I do have a patch route, but can't work out why it's not working.

**Error**

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/admin.5"
```

**admin_controller**

```
def edit
 @admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
  if @admin.update_attributes(admin_params)
  flash[:success] = "Admin profile updated"
  redirect_to '/administration'
  else
    flash[:error] = "Unable to update account\n#{admin.errors.messages}"
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
        <%= form_for @admin do |f| %>

          <form class="m-t" role="form" action="#">
            <div class="form-group">
                      <%= f.label :name %>
                      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <%= f.label :email %>
                      <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <%= f.label :user_name %>
                      <%= f.text_field :user_name, class: 'form-control' %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <%= f.label :password %>
                      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
                      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <%= f.label :avatar %>
                      <%= f.file_field :avatar, class: 'form-control' %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" %>
                    </div>
                </form>

            <% end %>
```

Comment: Try using ***Rails*** `form_for` instead ***HTML form***.

Comment: Please show your `routes.rb` and `rake routes`.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the routes once more and there appeared to be a rogue route added which was stopping this!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simply a custom route which was stopping the **resources :admin** from working

Answer (score 0):

In your controller update change /administration in:

```
redirect_to @admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Side note: 
In your edit.html.erb form change f.text_field :email to f.email_field :email.  On mobile devices this will make the keypad come up with the '@' symbol at the bottom for a shortcut.